# Circle Puzzle... Replace the question marks

Tags: cipher, pattern, visual

Try replace the question marks in this picture!

[image]

Hint:

> [image]

Comment: I almost understand, then.. no.  Is the red fields correct?

Comment: Yes, they are. Also, the different colors are randomly chosen by me(so blue could of been yellow or grey could of been red etc) but they do stand for different things/commands. And, of course, the puzzle *starts* with ####.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I knew the pentagon... Maybe the rest are E,1,1.  If different colors only mean different ways to get the first 8 prime numbers. Yellow meaning adding the digits, red meaning reversing the number.
>  I was trying to find a more specific function with colors also related to their actual color...
>  Edit: now I see there is more: at least the opposing colors have a similar function (add and "transform")

Comment: Yes, this is the intended answer :)

Comment: I was thinking yellow * grey (if only the number of letters are counted) is 24,so the total content of the opposing same color sectors is 24 with the pentagon,although not with 12, but with 13.(There was a question mark). Blue * red is 12, so E fits, but what about the reds? Since you added a clue by marking at least one white field, my version is weak and your solution is clear. (I just wanted to say, maybe you shouldn't have helped so much more, because you made it from difficult to easy, it was a difficult but solvable puzzle immediately at the first picture)

Comment: Ok :) 1 day had passed by without no answers(decent amount of viewers though) so i wanted to make it easier for that reason, but yeah, wasn't much of a challenge after i added the new picture.